# Changing the grid direction in Singularitygs

Tags: grid, singularitygs

I have read [Grid Direction](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-Options#grid-direction) section of the Singularitygs but could not figure out how can I change the direction of the grid. Would someone please clarify the solution?

Comment: Could you add a snippet?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to change the direction of the body grid. So the columns should be counted from right to left. right now by using @include grid-span(4,9), to find the 9nth column it start to count from left to right but for RTL site it should start from Right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the answer: just define a variable $direction: both and it is done.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide a code snippet? I couldn't figure out how to apply it. Thanks!